# What's causing my code not to display specific messages to the console?

Tags: c#, search, console

I am really close to finishing this little program that I've typed up but I'm encountering an issue where there's a portion of my code that's not being displayed to the console.

I have the console ask the user how many numbers they have that they want to be included in an array, and it will also ask the user for each number they have, and will lastly ask them what search method they want to use (binary, linear, or bubble).

**The part that I want to be displayed to the console, is where it will ask the user what number they're looking for**, the user will type that number in, and will display the number, as well as where that number has been stored at (index).

```
namespace Searching_Algorithm
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String userChoice;
            int element, searchElement, index;

            Console.WriteLine("Hello! Welcome to my Searching and Sorting Algorithm");
            Console.WriteLine("What search/sort method would you like to do?");
            userChoice = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("How many numbers do you have?");

            element = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] array = new int[element];


for (int i = 0; i < element; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number: ");
    array[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}

if (userChoice == "Binary Search")
{
    Console.WriteLine("What number are you looking for? ");
    searchElement = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    index = binarySearch(array, 0, element - 1, searchElement);
    if (index == -1)
        Console.WriteLine("The element you are looking for is not in the list.");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("The element you are looking for is at index " + index);
    //this part above is not being displayed for some reason and I've tried to fix it but
    //can't figure out why 

}

if (userChoice == "Linear Search")
{
    Console.WriteLine("What number are you looking for? ");
    searchElement = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    index = linearSearch(array, searchElement);
    if (index == -1)
        Console.WriteLine("\nThe element you are looking for is not in the list.");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("\nThe element you are looking for is at index " + index);
    //this part above is not being displayed for some reason and I've tried to fix it but
    //can't figure out why                     
}

if (userChoice == "Bubble Sort")
{
    bubbleSort(array);
    Console.WriteLine("After sorting using bubble sort Array is: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(array[i]);
    }

}

static void bubbleSort(int[] arr)
{
    int n = arr.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++)
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1])
            {
                int temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = temp;
            }
}

static int linearSearch(int[] arr, int x)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == x)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
static int binarySearch(int[] arr, int l,int r, int x)
{
    if (r >= l)
    {
        int mid = l + (r - l) / 2;
        if (arr[mid] == x)
            return mid;
        if (arr[mid] > x)
            return binarySearch(arr, l, mid - 1, x);
        return binarySearch(arr, mid + 1, r, x);
    } 
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Show the part where `userChoice` is assigned

Comment: alright I added it to the code

Comment: Expressions like `userChoice == "Binary Search"` are _case-sensitive_.  Perhaps you want `userChoice.Equals ("binary search", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);`? -  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Equals_System_String_System_StringComparison_

Answer (score 1):

This works just fine if you give *exactly correct* input. String comparisons are, by default, case-sensitive, and even the slightest mistake, a case mismatch, or an extra space, can result in comparison being false. In Console programs such as this, it's better to give the user a set of predefined choices, and proceed if a valid choice is made.

```
int choice = 0;
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Select a search method.");
    Console.WriteLine("1. Binary Search");
    Console.WriteLine("2. Linear Search");
    Console.WriteLine("3. Bubble Sort");
    Console.WriteLine("99. Exit");
    Console.Write("Enter your choice number: ");
    var input = Console.ReadLine();
    if (int.TryParse(input, out choice))
    {
        switch (choice)
        {
            case 99:
                break;
            case 1:
                // Call Binary Search
                break;
            case 2:
                // Call Linear Search
                break;
            case 3:
                // Call Bubble Sort
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid choice.");
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid choice.");
    }
} while (choice != 99);
```

Answer (score 0):

Expressions like `userChoice == "Binary Search"` are *case-sensitive*.

Perhaps you want:

```
userChoice.Equals ("binary search", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

e.g. change:

```
if (userChoice == "Binary Search") 
{
   ... 
}
```

...to:

```
if (userChoice.Equals ("binary search", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) 
{ 
   ... 
}
```